# Embed HTML in a MS Word file

Tags: javascript, css, ms-word, xhtml

I'm trying to embed HTML into a MS Word file so that when this page is loaded via hyperlink from website it will follow the rules set in my CSS/javascript. I also want to embed this code into the file:

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 1) }, 100);">
```

Would this be possible?

Comment: If you want the MS doc to open with the same HTML, CSS, and JS as the rest of the site... why not just create a new page for your site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. Any code you wish to write in a Word document must be written in a format that Word supports (such as, last time I looked at it, Visual Basic for Applications), not as embedded HTML.

Comment: You can however include HTML via an AltChunk (AlternativeFormatInputPart), which Word 2007+ will convert automatically when the docx is first opened.